# Select option on laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hi i m trying to insert a `<select> <option> 1 </option> </select>` but laravel not detect it in the request object. There is another option to put a spinner in a form? What i should use?

Here is my code:

**tickets/create.blade.html**

```
      <form action="{{ route('tickets.store') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="col s12">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
</div>
<div class="col s12">
  <input type="text" name="content" value="{{ old('content') }}">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input type="submit" value="Crear Incidencia">
  </div>
</div></form>
```

**TicketsController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    return $request->all();
}
```

Response:

> {"_token":"mnqsWAG9DQ7s8cCvHWmFsgJlHl2aqgMP9RvmfhRt","title":"Hello","content":"Bye"}

As you see the request not contains the number that i selected.

Comment: Add a `name` property to your select

Comment: Omg true. Thaks how i could forgot